# Can make iterate over a list of sources and give me alphabetic keys for each item?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a rule like this¹:

```
SOURCES = one.pdf two.pdf three.pdf

out.pdf: $(SOURCES)
    pdftk $^ cat output $@
```

This works great as long as I only want to use `$^` as a space separated list, but now lets ay I need to prefix each value with something. In the case of pdftk I need to name each input stream with a capital leter in order to fetch page ranges from each. If I want the first page of all the input files I need to run a command like this:

```
pdftk A=one.pdf B=two.pdf C=three.pdf cat A1 B1 C1 output out.pdf …
```

I am aware of the foreach function that I could iterate over something like this:

```
pdftk $(foreach SOURCE,$^,A=$(SOURCE))
```

…but of course `A=one.pdf A=two.pdf A=three.pdf` isn't going to get me very far. How can I both iterate over the list of inputs and assotiate them with keys from another array? Note I also need the length and keys from that other array to use again as handles in the rest of the command line.

Is GNU Make able to handle this situation gracefully or should I write a little wrapper script?

¹ <sub>Note this use case is simplified for the purpose of this question, the actual list of sources is generated at runtime and the length is not known, so hard coding a substitute array or changing the filenames to A.pdf B.pdf so that the basename can be used as the pdftk handle won't work.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language implemented by GNU make is not a general purpose language, which makes this kind of string processing awkward. I suggest to use a language more suitable to string processing--what about a little perl such as

```
SOURCES = one.pdf two.pdf three.pdf

out.pdf: $(SOURCES)
    @echo pdftk $$(perl -e '$$x=65; \
     foreach (@ARGV) { \
      $$a .= sprintf "%c=%s ", $$x, $$_; \
      $$b .= sprintf "%c1 ", $$x; ++$$x; \
     }; print "$$a cat $$b output $@\n"' $^)

$ make
pdftk A=one.pdf B=two.pdf C=three.pdf cat A1 B1 C1 output out.pdf
```

This is pretty flexible and extensible.